# How can I convert this code from SQL to Linq

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

How can I convert this below code from SQL to Linq

```
SELECT CF.CustomerProfileId,CF.Salutation,CF.Gender,CF.LastName,
           CF.DateOfBirth,AD.Line1,AD.Line2,AD.Line3,AD.Line4,AD.Line5,
           AD.Country,AD.ElectronicAddressDesc,NCIType.NationalCustomerIdentifierTypeDesc,
           NCI.NationalCustomerIdentifier from CustomerProfile CF
           left join Address AD on CF.CustomerProfileId = CF.CustomerProfileId
           left join NationalCustomerIdentifiers NCI on CF.CustomerProfileId = NCI.CustomerProfileId
           left join NationalCustomerIdentifierType NCIType on NCI.NationalCustomerIdentifierTypeId = NCIType.NationalCustomerIdentifierTypeId
          where CF.CustomerProfileId = @CustomerProfileid  and CF.Version = @Version
```

Comment: If it where me, i would create a view from that query and just import that view in your code.

Comment: Hint. Try breaking this up into multiple logical LINQ queries and then join them using defered execution the same way you would refactor your C#/VB code into managable chunks. Hint2: Use DefaultIfEmpty for Left joins OR see hint 3. Hint3: Use the natural associations between objects to avoid joins entirely.

Comment: It seems DefaultIfEmpty is not working for Linq to entity. After spending lot of time looking for left outer join, I finally decided to with VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make several left joins in LINQ. This is possible though will look not very good (linq is not very comfortable when dealing with joins other than inner).
[Here is a microsoft example of left join in linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) It only joins two tables but you can extend it. And if you don't like how the result looks - than make a view or an sproc.